# Common shared class for webservice call

Tags: ios, design-patterns, delegates, singleton, nsurlsession

Let me clear my question. I want a common shared class to call a webservice. And also I want to handle the data and error I get in the response using a Block.

I got the answer for that. As **Amin** said I can make a shared insctance as below:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
static NetworkManager *sharedInstance = nil;
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    sharedInstance = [[NetworkManager alloc]init];
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfig = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfig delegate:sharedInstance delegateQueue:nil];
});
return sharedInstance;
}
```

After that I can define a method as below:

```
-(void) fetchDataForURL : (NSString*)urlString postData:(NSDictionary*)dataDic WithCompletionBlock : (void(^) (NSDictionary *responseDictionary, NSError *error)) completionBlock
{
  // sending request here using NSURlConnection or NSURLSession

  // whatever data I get here I can get that data in the completionBlock declared in the method

        completionBlock(jsonDic, error);
}
```

Now, I can call the method in any class using the shared instance. And also I can get the data in the completion block.

Hope I made it little clear.
Thanks all for your help.

Comment: What question...? you want a sample code of NSURLSession?

Comment: I think requirement is, one model class which handles all webservice call using NSURLSession, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty unsure, what you want to do, too. Basically I understand your Q that way that you want to get the responses of all requests in one shared instance of a class `NetworkManager`? Right?

First of all you should re-think your design. "Collecting all in one" is like a global var code smell. However, …

A. Create a shared instance of the network manager. This is the usual pattern:

```
@implemenation NetworkManager
…
+ (instancetype)sharedInstance
{
  static NetworkManager *sharedInstance = nil;
  static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
  dispatch_once(&onceToken, 
  ^{
    sharedInstance = [[NetworkManager alloc] init];
  });
  return sharedInstance;
}
```

B. Use the shared instance in a completion block. For example:

```
[NSURLSession dataTaskWithURL:… completionHandler:
^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error)
{
  NetworkManager *networkManager = [NetworkManager sharedInstance];
  [networkManager processData:data]; // Or whatever you want to do.
}
```

Additionally it might be useful to set the network manager as delegate of the session.

Comment: Thanks Amin. I wanted this only. My other doubt is how will I get the **data**  from the block in the other class.

Comment: Again I'm unsure, what you want to do. But if you want to get the data in many instances of many classes, first this is a good idea (read the intro of my answer) and second simply use that instance in the block.